# Django: Combine 3 separate 'filters()' into single query

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have following piece of code

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    prefetch = ['vendor', 'picture']
    context['most_popular_products'] = Product.objects.filter(is_popular=True)[:5].prefetch_related(*prefetch)
    context['coming_soon_products'] = Product.objects.filter(is_coming_soon=True)[:5].prefetch_related(*prefetch)
    context['recent_products'] = Product.objects.all()[:5].prefetch_related(*prefetch)
    return context
```

As you see there are 3 separate calls for 5 latest `most_popular`, `coming_soon` and `recent` products.
It there a way to reduce number of database calls?

I'd like to construct single query like,

```
popular, coming_soon, recent = Product.objects.filter...and.so.on
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. Can't think of a query to do this in SQL, and as such it makes me believe that the same isn't possible through the Django ORM.
But keep in mind that this could just be because I haven't looked deep enough.

Comment: In which Django version?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.. But you can use one queryset and filter from it.

i.e.

```
products = Product.objects.all()
recent_products = products[:5]
coming_soon_products = products.filter(is_coming_soon=True)
most_popular_products = porducts.filter(is_popular=True)
```

Comment: This will also generate the same number of queries.

Comment: There *might* be some optimization to select the largest dataset using .values_list() and then "filter" it programmatically. Would cut down on the requests, but might not be a win anyway, idk